# Font Awesome SASS with Omega 4 Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, sass, font-awesome

I have an issue getting Font Awesome get running in Omega 4 subtheme on Drupal 7.

I have installed Font Awesome Sass as follows:

1) Added **gem 'font-awesome-sass'** to projects Gemfile so it looks like this:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

group :development do

  # Sass, Compass and extensions.
  ..
  ..
  gem 'font-awesome-sass'
  ..
  ..

end
```

2) I did go to my subtheme's folder in terminal and then:

```
$ bundle
```

once finished I did get following response:

```
Resolving dependencies...
...
...
Using font-awesome-sass (4.0.2)
...
...
Your bundle is complete!
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

To me it looks like all went well - no errors at all.

I have added @import "font-awesome"

to [THEME-NAME].styles.scss as follows:

```
// Import external libraries.
@import "compass";
@import "breakpoint";
@import "singularitygs";
@import "toolkit-no-css";
@import "font-awesome";
```

Once I run $ drush omega-guard I get the following output (including errors)

```
    error sass/[THEME-NAME].no-query.scss (Line 6 of sass/[THEME-NAME].styles.scss: File to import not found or unreadable: font-awesome.
Load paths:
  /Users/[USER]/Sites/drupal/sites/all/themes/[THEME-NAME]/sass
  /Users/[USER]/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@global/gems/compass-0.12.2/frameworks/blueprint/stylesheets
  /Users/[USER]/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@global/gems/compass-0.12.2/frameworks/compass/stylesheets
  /Users/[USER]/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@global/gems/compass-normalize-1.4.3/stylesheets
  /Users/[USER]/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@global/gems/compass-rgbapng-0.2.1/lib/stylesheets
  /Users/[USER]/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@global/gems/breakpoint-2.0.7/stylesheets
  /Users/[USER]/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@global/gems/singularitygs-1.1.2/stylesheets
  /Users/[USER]/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@global/gems/compass-blend-modes-0.0.2/stylesheets
  /Users/[USER]/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@global/gems/color-schemer-0.2.7/stylesheets
  /Users/[USER]/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@global/gems/toolkit-1.3.8/stylesheets
  /Users/[USER]/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@global/gems/susy-1.0.9/sass
  /Users/[USER]/Sites/drupal/sites/all/themes/[THEME-NAME]/sass
  Compass::SpriteImporter
  Sass::Globbing::Importer)
    error sass/[THEME-NAME].styles.scss (Line 6: File to import not found or unreadable: font-awesome.
Load paths:
  /Users/[USER]/Sites/drupal/sites/all/themes/[THEME-NAME]/sass
  /Users/[USER]/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@global/gems/compass-0.12.2/frameworks/blueprint/stylesheets
  /Users/[USER]/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@global/gems/compass-0.12.2/frameworks/compass/stylesheets
  /Users/[USER]/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@global/gems/compass-normalize-1.4.3/stylesheets
  /Users/[USER]/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@global/gems/compass-rgbapng-0.2.1/lib/stylesheets
  /Users/[USER]/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@global/gems/breakpoint-2.0.7/stylesheets
  /Users/[USER]/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@global/gems/singularitygs-1.1.2/stylesheets
  /Users/[USER]/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@global/gems/compass-blend-modes-0.0.2/stylesheets
  /Users/[USER]/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@global/gems/color-schemer-0.2.7/stylesheets
  /Users/[USER]/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@global/gems/toolkit-1.3.8/stylesheets
  /Users/[USER]/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@global/gems/susy-1.0.9/sass
  /Users/[USER]/Sites/drupal/sites/all/themes/[THEME-NAME]/sass
  Compass::SpriteImporter
  Sass::Globbing::Importer)
Compilation took 2.234s
16:06:45 - INFO - Guard::Compass is waiting to compile your stylesheets.
16:06:45 - INFO - LiveReload is waiting for a browser to connect.
16:06:45 - INFO - Guard is now watching at '/Users/[USER]/Sites/drupal/sites/all/themes/[THEME-NAME]'
[1] guard(main)> 16:06:46 - INFO - Browser connected.
16:06:56 - INFO - Browser connected.
16:07:15 - INFO - Browser connected.
```

I will appreciate any help with this as I'm really clueless and I spend a day on this already.

Thank you for your time!

Tom

Comment: This might be very simple. The error is ruby can't find `sass/[THEME-NAME].styles.scss`. I'm guessing you've defined: `[THEME-NAME].styles.scss`, literally, in one of your `*.inc` files for omega. Find where that's defined (either in theme/theme.info or in the layouts/*.inc files) and swap [THEME-NAME] with your theme name.

Comment: Alright, perhaps you obfuscated your themename. However, I tried doing likewise and have an identical error. I found this ticket: https://github.com/FortAwesome/font-awesome-sass/pull/10 don't know if this is related?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you still need this answered, but the SASS gem is only designed to work with rails. To use Font Awesome with Drupal themes, call it drupal_add_css() in a preprocess function.